# How I can config the fluentd Proxy for install plugins?

Tags: linux, proxy, rhel6, fluentd

I can't install a plugin at fluentd. i've set the proxy-variable at the System (rhel) but it have no influence.

```
$ td-agent --gemfile grok-plugin/Gemfile
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
  Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
  Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
  Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
$ echo $HTTP_PROXY
  http://proxy.de:port
$ echo $HTTPS_PROXY
  http://proxy.de:port
$ echo $https_proxy
  http://proxy.de:port
$ echo $http_proxy
  http://proxy.de:port
```

Please can you help me to set the proxy for the gem-install?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. I have an other Problem and it gave me an approach. In rhel6 you must write the proxy without `http://`, then it works. (Write the proxy without protocol, is only the solution for this problem)